# clearing :active pseudo-class on current element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-selectors, qtwebkit

I've implemented my own *kinetic scrolling* component that generally works very well. My problem is that link elements in the page that use the **:active** pseudo-class maintain their :active state even when the user swipes and thus scrolls the screen (which means that the mouseup won't generate a "click").

Currently I already can avoid the "click" event but the visual feedback (:active) does not match the behavior.

So I need to directly or indirectly clear the ":active" via JavaScript. Perhaps creating a dummy link and "activate" it via JavaScript would solve the problem, but I had no luck with that.

To find a solution a made a simple testcase that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/LkAXd/2/

Any ideas?

Note I just need a solution that works with Webkit.

### Update

This dirty hack clears the :active pseudoclass from the element `l1` (basically by briefly removing it from the document):

```
var next = l1.nextSibling;
document.body.removeChild(l1);
document.body.insertBefore(l1, next);
```

The problem is that `document.activeElement` apparently does **not** reference links that just got a mousedown (they don't get focus that way), so I have no way to know which element currently is :active.

Comment: Asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: I haven't tested, but maybe you can created a mouseup event in javascript, so the browser thinks the button is released?

Comment: @Mickey: not exactly the same. I just need to clear the ":active", so assuming that there can be only one ":active" element at a time, it would be enough to set another element as active (but no clue how to do that).

Comment: @Mr Lister: just tried that. That causes the link to be "clicked" but it remains ":active", unfortunately.

Comment: @FrankvanWijk rather than being so quick to point out potential duplicates and helping absolutely no one, maybe you should spend a moment to read the question and realize it is, in fact, a very different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood what you're trying to do, but you can get the active element using `document.querySelector`.

Adding the following code to your test case worked for me:

```
var aEl = document.querySelector("a:active"),  // Active Element
    nEl = aEl && aEl.nextSibling,              // The node following it
    pEl = aEl && aEl.parentNode;               // The parent node

if (aEl && pEl) {
    pEl.removeChild(aEl);
    pEl.insertBefore(aEl, nEl);
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/LkAXd/3/**

Since you tagged [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit), I'm assuming you're in control of the environment and don't need to worry about legacy browsers.

Comment: Wonderful! That's working just fine. I'm not really happy about the removeChild/insertChild hack, but at least that works. Is there a specific reason why you used insertAdjacentElement() instead of the standard insertBefore() ?

Comment: @UdoG: just a bit of a brain malfunction.  I changed it very shortly afterwards (as you can see in the answer's code), but forgot to [update the link](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/LkAXd/4/).  Oh well. :-)