# How to change text-selection styles with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, textselection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

How do you do something equal to:

```
::selection {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

in javascript?

Comment: @Pumbaa80: `::selection` is not a pseudo-class, though the principle of using JS to modify the document styles does apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.foobar::selection {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

---

```
element.className += " foobar";
```

Comment: I can't add the change as an edit, because an edit requires 6+ characters to be edited... but it should be `+= " foobar"` because otherwise the previous classname would not be separated from the new one

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: Already updated, but you're right. Thanks. :)

Comment: so there's no way to assign a (via js) generated color?

Comment: @peat-ar: To my knowledge, not without manipulating the style sheet. See the *possible duplicate* answer for more info.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was how to do it with javascript. This is a hybrid between CSS and JS.  So how do we do this with Javascript?