# how do I modify a :hover style using JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have a `:hover` style definition declared in the CSS stylesheet file:

```
.myclass:hover {
    border-color: red;
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/zdLfy');
}
```

Now, under given conditions, I want to change the `background-image` for this hover style.

I don't know how to do this using JavaScript / jQuery. Is this possible? How?

Comment: I think I didn't write the question well. I know what people has answered by now (thanks), but it is not what I asked.

Comment: You mean you want to change the css style itself?

Comment: Look: the first part of the answer is a "YES" or "NO". Can I change the style? The ":hover" style, specifically.

Comment: You will have to use javascript to query the stylesheet and change the Css class.

Comment: @PSCoder: great... so my question should be "How can I interact with the CSS stylesheet using JavaScript / jQuery?" Do you know?

Comment: Yes that would make more sense. But why can't you define another class with that background image and change the class based on your condition.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: @Zenith: You are right. I tried to delete my question, but SO didn't allow because it has answers... Voted for "close" now.

Comment: @Zenith: indeed, it is a copy/paste slightly changed... there is another answer which contains an interesting trick, I liked it and it seems to work - I've accepted it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new style tag cascade over the previous declaration. assuming the css in in the head tag

```
$('head').append('<style>#element:hover {/
    background-image: url("http://new.image/url");/
}/
<style>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#element').hover(function() {
//on hover
    if(condition === true) {
        $(this).addClass('newBGImage');
    }
}, function() {
//when hover ends
    if($(this).hasClass('newBGImage')) {
        $(this).removeClass('newBGImage');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your CSS be something like this:

```
.myclass:hover {
    border-color: red;
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/zdLfy'); 
}

.specialCondition:hover {
    background-image: url('http://anotherURL');
}
```

And then, for that special condition do:

```
$('.myclass').addClass('specialCondition');
```

And when the special condition is no longer there, remove the class:

```
$('.myclass').removeClass('specialCondition');
```

This way you keep your background-urls where they belong, in the CSS

Comment: +1 I think this is what I will actually do. In fact, this is really the right thing to do! And your answer, although simple, is very well written. Thank you! I would like to accept your answer too, but Musa's dirty trick actually DOES what I wanted and asked for.

Comment: Also, surprisingly, from the answers by now which mentioned the "condition", yours is the only one which considered it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a class that has the new background and then on hover use something like

```
$(this).addClass("YourClassName");
```

and then on leave

```
$(this).removeClass("YourClassName");
```