# Change attribute of CSS Pseudo classes (:hover) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

Is it even possible to change the pseudo classes with jQuery ? Is there any workaround for achieving this?

Comment: it is not possible to use jQuery for such cases

Comment: A few days ago I found a jQuery-style library to access stylesheets, but now I can't find it again, all I find are stylesheet switchers.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you elaborate? What exactly do you want to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I created the following function to change my hover class

```
var setPseudoClass = function (rule, prop, value)
    {
        var sheets = document.styleSheets;
        var slen = sheets.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < slen; i++)
        {
            var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
            if (rules)
            {
                var rlen = rules.length;
                for (var j = 0; j < rlen; j++)
                {
                    if (rules[j].selectorText && rules[j].selectorText.indexOf(rule) > 0)
                    {
                        alert(rules[j].selectorText);
                        rules[j].style[prop] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a class selector to your CSS, and toggle the class on and off for the element you would like to change style/anything when you hover over it.

Here are other suggestions: 
[Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

[Dynamic CSS pseudo class styles with jQuery](http://www.4pmp.com/2009/11/dynamic-css-pseudo-class-styles-with-jquery/)

Comment: Definitely this. Using Javascript to change individual CSS properties is very messy.. just switch the class!

Comment: The problem with changing the class is that you might be using a color-picker.