# How can I select (test) styles applied with an :after pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element

I have an :after pseudo element applying a font awesome icon to my table headers. I want to write a test to make sure that the icons are really there by selecting the element and testing its style. **How can I get this style with jquery or plain javascript?**

```
&:after {
    content: "\f0de";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
  }
```

I've tried `$('th:after')`, `$('th\\:after')`, `$('th::after')` and a few more things... but looking around the internet it seems like maybe it's not possible at all to test pseudo elements?

**EDIT**
The answers in the duplicate talk about strategies around adding/editing a pseudo element. I just wanted to get the content inside it for a test. I also can't do the trick of conditionally applying a class that contains an after pseudo element because I need to hook into the existing class that the framework i'm using applies and override it. The 2nd answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin) is how i got it to work.

```
var testString = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('thead th'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript

Comment: This is not possible. Pseudo elements are not part of DOM and cannot be selected.

Comment: @SalmanA - You realize that isn't correct right? Everything on the page is part of the DOM.

Comment: @TravisJ no, this is incorrect. Pseudo elements are silimar to "generated content" much like bullets on `UL` and numbers on `OL` elements. They are not part of DOM.

Comment: @SalmanA - I assumed that it should have been in one of the text nodes. You are right, it is not part of the DOM.