# Is there a way to set css :focus using JS to all document

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to set css `:focus` using JS to all document without running a script for checking every element? Something like this, perhaps:

`document.style.focus.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";` ?

I know this won't work, but is there any way to do something similar to this? If not, then how should I set the `:focus` globally for some specific style?

The only way I got is to run for all elements and only then attach styles for them, like this:

```
function TheFunction() {
    var findthemall = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < findthemall.length; i++) {
        findthemall[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        //etc, etc, etc...
    }
}
```

But I think it's a bad idea

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript